# How to configure AtmosphereHandlerService: No AtmosphereHandler found message?

Tags: grails, websocket, comet, atmosphere

I create atmosphere handlers dynamically. In case of server restart, since the created handlers are lost, I get "No AtmosphereHandler found" exception. I want to configure this message, and send it to client, so that client can send request to re-create new handler. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try using the onError(AtmosphereResponse) atmosphere request callback on the client? If the error is caught on the request handler of the client then you could use the handler to reconnect.

Comment: @bizmark thanks, but I have completely changed the architecture by this time and no more using Atmosphere now. Though I have thought of using AtmosphereInterceptor before changing design. I am just curious now, that will this work? [link](http://atmosphere.github.com/atmosphere/apidocs/org/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereInterceptor.html)